# How to add a new module to Spark source and make it work in spark-shell?

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I'm using IDEA15 and I want to add a new module to the spark source.

I clicked File->new->module and chose a maven module. Then I set the "Add as module to..." option and the "Parent" to "Spark Project Parent POM". After typing in the module name I clicked "Finish".

Then I added some code to my new module and build it using the follwing command

"build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package"

The project was built successfully but in the spark-shell I can't import my newly added classes.

I wonder what's wrong with what I've done and how can I add a new module and then import it in the spark-shell?

Thanks a lot!

PS: I'm sure there's no problem with my code. I added my code in the mllib module and it worked.
Maybe some dependency is missing but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven build created a jar file from your build (should be in the `target/` directory inside your project folder).

When you start the Spark shell, you can define the jar files to include in your shell. You can include your jar there like this:

spark-shell --jars /path/to/your/project.jar

Also you could give it a try, to install your project inside your local Maven repository, it is possible that the Spark shell can pick it up (so you don't have to specify `--jars` each time you run the it).

For this, run your Maven build command with `clean install` instead of `clean package` at the end.

Comment: I specify --jars argument and now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's my first time asking questions on stackoverflow. So sorry for not accepting you answer... Now it's done :)